# how to fetch and load large amount of data into jquery datable using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

[image: here is the image of my error]hi i am using jquery's datatable plugin and it was working fine when my data was around 600 but now my data is 28000 and the data table is getting slow to load it so is der a way where i can make its execution faster so that it wont take much time to load m a newbie in php so i knw just the common syntax. can anyone please help me 
here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datatables').dataTable({
           "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
            "aaSorting":[[2, "desc"]],
            "bJQueryUI":true,
            "sAjaxSource": "ajax.php"
        });
    })

</script>

 <table id="datatables" class="display">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Srno.</th>
             <th>Brno.</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Address</th>
             <th>City</th>
             <th>Pin</th>
             <th>Mobile</th>
             <th>Actions</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
  </table>

here is ajax.php
<?php
require("includes/dbconnect.php");
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

/* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array('grno', 'brno', 'name', 'address', 'city', 'pin', 'mobile');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "grno";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "mdb";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user'] = "root";
$gaSql['password'] = "rajF@1998";
$gaSql['db'] = "mdb";
$gaSql['server'] = "localhost";



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/*
 * MySQL connection
 */
$gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']) or
        die('Could not open connection to server');

mysql_select_db($gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link']) or
        die('Could not select database ' . $gaSql['db']);


/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if (isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1') {
    $sLimit = "LIMIT " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['iDisplayStart']) . ", " .
            mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['iDisplayLength']);
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if (isset($_GET['iSortCol_0'])) {
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < intval($_GET['iSortingCols']); $i++) {
        if ($_GET['bSortable_' . intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] == "true") {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] . "
                    " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSortDir_' . $i]) . ", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace($sOrder, "", -2);
    if ($sOrder == "ORDER BY") {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if (isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "") {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch']) . "%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
    if (isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_' . $i] != '') {
        if ($sWhere == "") {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        } else {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_' . $i]) . "%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns)) . "
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
$rResult = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or die(mysql_error());

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or die(mysql_error());
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(" . $sIndexColumn . ")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or die(mysql_error());
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    //"sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)) {
    $row = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        if ($aColumns[$i] == "version") {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[$aColumns[$i]] == "0") ? '-' : $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
        } elseif ($aColumns[$i] === "vouchno") {

            $row[] = "<a href=\"invoice.php?ORDERID=" . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"View Invoice: " . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . "\">" . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . "</a><a href=\"invoice.php?action=delete&ORDERID=" . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . "\"onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"../images/icons/trash-can-delete.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></a>";
        } else if ($aColumns[$i] != ' ') {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Don't you want to add paging on this page? Becasue In case of Paging you need to fatch only few records and the performacne will be far better then loading complete data at once.

Comment: but the data table will itself make the paging rite?

Comment: No In case of paging implementation you need to set the range in select query. let say you want to show 100 rows per page so only 100 row will be fatched at a time and you need to make your query with parameter of data range.

Comment: yea i implemented the limit as per ur advice but it onli fetches the record which is set the limit to but i want to show my all records

Comment: The attached screenshot showing JSON formatting error. So there might be some problem in Database records. Either you have not handled the NULL or might be some special character in result set.  For some alternates for optimization you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: i think so since i am a newbie i dnt have much knowledge about it so can please help me in it

Comment: I would not be able to help you exactly becasue I don't have setup here so better to put some alert in loop or use debugging.

Comment: sir actually the thing is i really dnt knw anything about it mo jus a starter so please help me it would be a huge favor

Answer (score 2):

Try considering [Datatable Server Side Processing example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) from their datatables website.

Answer (score 1):

If you using [this jQuery plugin](http://www.datatables.net/index), you would want to look at [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).

instead of using a file you create a php file what output a json:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `vouchno`, grno, brno, `name`, `address`, `city`, `pin`, mobile FROM mdb") or die(mysql_error());
$response = array();
// mysql_fetch_assoc is faster the mysql_fetch_array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $response [] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

And of course you need to discover the rest your self.

Comment: but sir i dntknw hw to do it

Comment: can u just help in showing of how should i write a php file which will output a json?